# FedEx Setting with Magento is not Working

Tags: magento, fedex

I need to set up FedEx Shipping method in Magento.  I have Account Number, Meter Number, Key & password.  I successfully inserted them in the corresponding fields, but when i check an item there is no FedEx shipping option available.

I do not understand.  Is my access information is wrong or there are others things needed?

Comment: What version of magento?

Comment: @MrGlass magento version is 1.7 CE.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I have turned on logging, but the results on the log look fine. What does your log show?

Comment: i found my fault.everything of my setting was correct but product weight was not set.to working with Fedex shipping,product weight must be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found my fault.everything of my setting was correct but product weight was not set.Product weight must be assigned for FedEx.

Answer (score 0):

Enable fedex shipping logs and check what is the response you are getting from fedex.

you might missing some parameters.

for setup of a fedex shipping method you can refer [Fedex Setup](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-fedex-shipping-in-magento/)